# macromedia.jdbc.sqlserverbase.ddb_leaks

Tags: coldfusion

Has anyone come across memory leaks containing the macromedia.jdbc.sqlserverbase classes?  Using MAT, I can see 30,000+ instances of the above classes retained size is 1.3GB, each one appears to map to a single instance of a (different) CFQuery. Ie, I can see the query SQL in there, and I can see the results (in a TDS object)

The app is kind of busy, but there is no way that there is 30,000+ line CFQuery tags.
We are not caching the CfQuery tags.

I'm really struggling to see the GC root that is holding onto these.

Comment: Paths to GC roots are as follows: PookSkimmerThread -> JDBC Pool -> FusionReactor.jdbc -> macromedia.jdbc.sqlserverbase.dde -> macromedia.jdbc.sqlserverbase.ddj

Comment: _"We are not caching the CfQuery tags."_ - maybe not deliberately, but are they all scoped appropriately? (i.e. use var keyword / local scope in functions) If not, you may well have a bunch of queries sitting in the variables scope of persistent CFCs...

Comment: We have 100% the same issue. Here we see over 70% of leaked memory by macromedia.jdbc.sqlserverbase.dddg. It will never GC'd. It looks like a bug we need to investigate with Adobe.

Answer (score 1):

We use the  driver that ships with CF for some very high traffic sites with heavy DB usage and do not see issues with it.  The only issue I have seen is related to networking - where a port will auto-sync to get a different speed or duplex and leave connections sort of hanging. It only happens with certain switches but when it does it *sort of* behaves like that (a bunch of hanging connections). FYI - on a busy server you might have 30k+ dereferenced objects (instances of this or that) hanging around waiting for GC. That wouldn't be unusual. Does GC Recover these objects? Do you get your 1.3Gigs back?

Comment: We have been running CF for years under much higher traffic conditions without issue. GC is unable to recover space and we end up "crashing" - well, we restart before the actual OOM and GC overhead limit exceeded errors, but using HPJMeter, we can see there is a definite memory leak. We are taking heap dumps and MAT shows them as still being references objects so it does not look like GC will recover those.  One of the challenges are the MM JDBC drivers are obfuscated, so I can't tell for sure what ddb_ is.  (row or column or query)